# jQuery - how to select only links to new pages?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, fadeout

I have some code that goes like this, using jQuery, to fade out the main div when a user clicks a link:

```
$('a').click( function () { $('#content').fadeOut(); });
```

However, I really only want this to apply to links that open a new page in the same window, i.e. not anything with target="_blank" or anything that opens a lightbox or modal dialog or skips to an anchor within the document, because that is obviously not going to be very helpful when the window remains open but without the content.

So, how can I replace that 'a' with something that selects only the right kind of links - links that navigate the current window away to some other content (could be internal or external)?

Many, many thanks.
Dave

Comment: What do the links look like that open a dialog or a lightbox? Can you show some examples

Comment: Use different `id`s or `class`es on your anchor tags to distinguish between the links, and update your jQuery selector appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a class to those links and change the event handler with:

```
$('.myClass').click( function () { $('#content').fadeOut(); });
```

obviously, this can apply if you already know the links that are going away

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically? i.e. do an addClass('.myClass') to all the links that apply? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to filter on an attribute:

```
$('a[target!="_blank"]').click( function () { $('#content').fadeOut(); });
```

More on attribute selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Sorry just realised you wanted it when **not** `_blank`. Edited accordingly

Comment: Thanks, this is is a good start, but unfortunately this doesn't exclude links to page anchors or lightboxes/modal dialogs, so I still have that issue. I could make a list of all of these, in a similar fashion to what you've done here: href!="#", href!="javascript:void(0)" and so on, but for a watertight solution I'd rather somehow select only the links that open in the same window, rather than exhaustively excluding the ones that don't. a[target="_self"] doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: If your logic is too complex to do this, you need to use one of the other two solutions below then I would suggest.